# PHP Multiplying decimal variables

Tags: php, xml

I am trying to create a global price markup that will insert into the mysql table. I grab a variable from a simplexml element and multiply it by a number that is inserted by a form but the resulting answer is incorrect.

The variable calling from the xml file rounds up to a whole number and then multiples the $_post variable.

Sample..

```
$myprodprice = $myproduct->PRODUCTS_PRICE; // the xml value (sample is 2.33)
$mymarkup = $_post['mymarkup'];
echo $myprodprice;
echo $mymarkup;
$mymultiply = $myprodprice * $mymarkup;
echo $mymultiply;
```

Results will be

2.33

3.5

7

It ends up ignoring the xml variable decimal numbers when multiplying, but it will echo correctly otherwise.

Any help will be welcomed

Comment: I do a foreach which will supply a list of values, but a sample xml value would be 2.53

Comment: Why am I getting a thumbs down? Any response would be appreciated.

Comment: That did it. I tried numbers_format, money_format, so many different things. I didn't think floatval applied here. Thanks!

Comment: Cool! I wrote an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `floatval()` to convert the strings to float values before multiplying.